# Delete a run in the experiment of mlflow from the UI so the run does not exist in backend store

Tags: mlflow

I found deleting a `run` only change the state from `active` to `deleted`, because the run is still visible in the UI if searching by `deleted`.

Is it possible to remove a `run` from the UI to save the space? 
When removing a run, does the artifact correspond to the run is also removed?

If not, can the run be removed through rest call?

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer indeed deletes the experiment, not the run of an experiment.

In order to remove the directory one can use the mlflow API. Here is the script that removes all deleted runs:

```py
import mlflow
import shutil
    
def get_run_dir(artifacts_uri):
    return artifacts_uri[7:-10]
    
    
def remove_run_dir(run_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(run_dir, ignore_errors=True)
    
experiment_id = 1
deleted_runs = 2
    
exp = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient(tracking_uri='./mlflow/mlruns')
    
runs = exp.search_runs(str(experiment_id), run_view_type=deleted_runs)
    
_ = [remove_run_dir(get_run_dir(run.info.artifact_uri)) for run in runs]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, search_runs ignores the run_view_type and returns all runs in the experiment

Answer (score 2):

Whilst Grzegorz already provided a solution, I just wanted to provide an alternative solution using the MLFlow cli.

The cli has a command, `mlfLow gc`, which deletes runs in the deleted lifecycle stage.

check https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-gc

Comment: Doesn't work with a DB though, resulting in `This cli can only be used with a backend that allows hard-deleting runs`